# DDR3 1333Mhz Ram PC3-10600 vs PC3-10660 performance difference

Tags: memory, speed, ddr3

I've looked around and I'm unable to find a any real idea of how much performance difference that there is. The timings are the same as the RAM that is in my laptop but I wanted to expand it to 16GB and thus I bought some patriot ram that was on sale on newegg and had a 20usd gift card, after you purchased it. The only difference between it and the Samsung RAM that I have in my laptop(beyond manufacturer) is that the Patriot ram is DDR3 PC3-10660 and the patriot is PC3-10600.

I know that the difference is likely in some sort of speed but since there's no definitive guide, my guess is that it's the maximum throughput in some measurement. I'm going to say MB/s. If that is it, then I'm not going to worry since 60MB/s maximum throughput difference is not worth me spending 2x as much on ram that's going to be used for a ram disk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference.

The common module name of `DDR-1333` is `PC3-10600`, because its peak transfer rate is `10666.666... MB/s`.

Advertising the RAM modules as `PC3-10660` or even `PC3-10666` is simply marketing. It sounds higher, but it actually refers to the same thing.

Comment: ok thanks, I wasn't sure if it was some sort of "guaranteed" maximum throughput kind of like how SATA II is capable of 6Gbps but rarely does anything actually achieve that throughput. I'd upvote your answer but I cannot sadly. Glad to know that once again it all comes down to marketing, just like Monitors and TV screens. I thought ram would be semi-safe of such snake oil.